# Can I create a short-lived, limited access token from a long-lived one?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

If my web app's backend has a long-lived access token for a user, can I use it to create a short-lived access token to hand down to the client (a web page) for it to interact with the Facebook API?

Even better, could I create one that's both short-lived and limited in scope (e.g. only has `user_photos` scope), even if the long-term access token on my server has more permissions?

Comment: Embedding the JS SDK into your page will automatically get you a short-lived token if the user has authorized your app once (and if there is no server-side session where the long-lived token is already stored). But you can not ask for a new one with less permissions. (You could delete permissions, but that would take them away from your long-lived one as well.)

Comment: What's your use-case here? Is your app leaking access tokens to third parties?

Comment: @CBroe I don't want the frontend to depend on users being signed into the right Facebook account once they've connected one. For example if I'm using a friend's computer, *they* might be signed into Facebook already (and have authorized our app), but if I'm signed into our website as me, it should be using the Facebook API as me.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use my server's long-lived access token to create a new long-lived access token and hand to the JavaScript on the page, per [this API flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#long-via-code).

It would work but I don't like the idea of handing out long-lived tokens with full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to proxy the Facebook API for logged-in users. I’d make specific endpoints on our site that call Facebook with your stored long-lived access token.

This works and sounds good from a security perspective, but it'll be more work with little flexibility.